# Best way to create a Helper class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am retrieving some results from Database and then assigning the values to variables. But some of the fields in my records might contain null as well. I would like to check before assigning that the value does not contain any null.

Also there are some variable those are type int, so like to check before parsing to the specific type.

```
int iValue=int.parse(Helper.IsNull(dr[colName].toString()));
string strValue=Helper.IsNull(dr[colName].toString());
```

How should I create a helper class and what value should I return with IsNull method?

Thanks

Comment: This is probably too broad for SO, there are many ways to handle this. If your value contains a null you're going to get an exception trying to call ToString()

Comment: I disagree that the question is too broad, I think it can be answered in a few paragraphs (especially if the answer is described in terms of general logic, as opposed to providing actual code). However, you should rewrite the question to make it clear exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create an extension method

```
public static class Extension{
    public static T Isnull<T>(this Object value){
        if(value == null || value == DBNull.Value)
            return default(T);

        (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T)));
    }
}
```

being called so

```
int iValue = dr[colName].Isnull<int>();
string sValue = dr[colNameStr].Isnull<string>();
```

Comment: Just wondering what will be the value return in case of null value.

Comment: If it is an "int" will be zero if it is a "string" will be null and so on, ie, the default values ​​of the type of variable

Comment: so i don't want it to return 0 by default. If it is null i would like throw exception.

Comment: so just instead of returning "default (T)" throw the exception